# How do I calculate new div height and apply to gsap pin function when screensize changes

Tags: javascript, html, animation, gsap

I am new to gsap and its scrolltrigger plugin and now I have my first problem.

- I have 2 div elements next to each other.
- When you scroll down, the left one gets pinned until it reaches the bottom of the right one.
- I calculate the travel distance of the left div with `let travelDistance = rightDivHeight-leftDivHeight;`

The problem:
When the screen gets resized (phone/tablet tilt) the calculation is outdated because the height changes. That throws off the animation. Demo as pictures:

[image]

This is the code:

//html

```
<body>
    <div class="spacer">Spacer</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="left">Pinned</div>
        <div id="right">
            <div class="box">Box</div>
            <div class="box">Box</div>
            <div class="box">Box</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">Spacer</div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

//css

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.box {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 8px;
}
.spacer {

    height: 150vh;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: grey;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
}
#left {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}
#right {
    width: 60%;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    display: grid;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .box {
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

//javascript

```
let rightDivHeight = document.getElementById('right').clientHeight;
let leftDivHeight = document.getElementById('left').clientHeight;
let travelDistance = rightDivHeight-leftDivHeight;
console.log('TravelDistance Calc: '+ rightDivHeight+'px - '+leftDivHeight+'px = '+travelDistance+'px');

gsap.to("#left", {
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: "#left",
        start: "top center",
        end:  `+=${travelDistance}`,
        pin: true,
        markers: true,
        pinSpacing: false,
    }
});
```

How can I write a function that updates every time the screen size changes?
I already tried putting the code in a function and call it with `window.addEventListener('resize', updateRightDivHeight);` But this didn't update the animation :( Do I have to work on the gsap part?
Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a resize event listener to update the values when the window is resized.

```js
window.addEventListener( 'resize', updateHeights );

function updateHeights() {
  rightDivHeight = document.getElementById('right').clientHeight;
  leftDivHeight = document.getElementById('left').clientHeight;
  travelDistance = rightDivHeight-leftDivHeight;
}
```